# find four elements in array whose sum equal to a given number X

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I need help to find an algorithm that finds:

- four elements in array
- whose sum equal to a given number X
- in O(n^2*log(n))

prefer in pseudo-code or c,c++

Comment: Sounds like homework

Comment: Sounds like you need a method of finding all permutations of 4 unique indexes.

Comment: Are numbers greater than zero? Are all numbers unique?

Comment: Any restriction on X or numbers?

Comment: Do you mean that you want write a function that takes an `array`, its `length`, and a `value` and return a set of 4 members of the `array` whose sum is `value`?  Do you want it to return the set of all possible sets of 4 members whose sum is `value`?  What if there is none found?

Comment: Added homework tag since it's been an hour and nothing says it isn't.

Comment: For what it's worth, I remember seeing the problem before and hearing people having solutions involving a sort of `n^2` elements (presumably the sums of every pair) and then `n^2` binary searches, resulting in the requested complexity. I never figured out how they dealt with certain indices problems however. Just thought I'd share in case anyone wants to pursue this approach.

Comment: the numbers are not unique or positive, i need only one option, not all permutations of 4 numbers

Answer (score 31):

You can do it in O(n^2). Works fine with duplicated and negative numbers.

**edit** as Andre noted in comment, time is with use of hash, which has 'worst case' (although it's less likely than winning in a lottery). But you can also replace hashtable with balanced tree (TreeMap in java) and get guaranteed stable O(n^2 * log(n)) solution.

Hashtable `sums` will store all possible sums of two different elements. For each sum `S` it returns pair of indexes `i` and `j` such that `a[i] + a[j] == S` and `i != j`. But initially it's empty, we'll populate it on the way.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    // 'sums' hastable holds all possible sums a[k] + a[l]
    // where k and l are both less than i

    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
        int current = a[i] + a[j];
        int rest = X - current;
        // Now we need to find if there're different numbers k and l
        // such that a[k] + a[l] == rest and k < i and l < i
        // but we have 'sums' hashtable prepared for that
        if (sums[rest] != null) {
            // found it
        }
    }

    // now let's put in 'sums' hashtable all possible sums
    // a[i] + a[k] where k < i
    for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k) {
        sums[a[i] + a[k]] = pair(i, k);
    }
}
```

Let's say, `X = a[1] + a[3] + a[7] + a[10]`. This sum will be found when `i = 7`, `j = 10` and `rest = a[1] + a[3]` (indexes 1 and 3 will be found from hash)

Comment: If you use a Tree Map instead of a HashTable (which can have O(n) in the worst case), you're guaranteed to have O(log n) for the lookup of the sums.

You should also check that you're not using one number more than once.

Comment: @Andre I don't think we should consider worst case access time for hash, it's extremely unlikely to happen :) But if that's important, then TreeMap is a solution, yes.

Comment: @Andre  _You should also check that you're not using one number more than once_ It's already done. i and j are always equals and i < j. And hashtable contains sums for all different indexes k and l less than i.

Comment: you're right, I didn't realize the way you're updating the sums map and that it contains only indices < i. +1 from me.

Comment: The requested running time makes me think the instructors are expecting something other than hash tables. Also, I don't think we shouldn't consider the worst case for hashes. If the numbers are big enough, how will your solution fare for all equal numbers? This works if you use trees though, so +1.

Comment: @IVlad Actually, we need only one pair for each particular sum, so in case of all equal numbers hashtable will have only one element. It's still possible that lots of different sums will have same hash, just difficult to emulate.

Comment: @NikitaRybak +1 nice solution. suppose take an example of {2,3,4,5,7,9,10} now when your i=4 and j=5 then current=16 and rest = 23-16=7 (suppose x = 23 here). Noe the map only contains (2,5) but does not contain (4,5). So to get rid of the situation we can use the sum as key and list as value(so that multiple indexes can be stored.). But if many sums are equal then our time complexity can be o(n^3). Am i correct? Thanks.

Comment: @Trying In your example, sums[7] = (3, 0). So, you end up with indexes [0, 3, 4, 5]. Didn't understand the second part of your reply, but let me know if you'd like more information.

Comment: @NikitaRybak suppose x=23. Now when you reach i=4 and j=5 i.e. current = 16 and rest=7. 7 can be obtained by a[0]+a[3] and a[1]+a[2]. But the map will contain only one value for a given sum. So it will only contain (0,3) but will not contain (1,2). Hope it clarifies.

Comment: @Trying I see you point. The problem definition asks for a solution, not for all solutions. You're right that finding all solutions would take longer. If all the numbers are equal, there're O(n^4) solutions, which means at least O(n^4) time.

Comment: I don't understand how do you make sure you're not using one number more than once? I read your comment in reply to Andre, but it s still unclear. could you please elaborate this?

Answer (score 4):

Abusing the fact that no memory constrain is specified. And using the usual divide and conquer approach.

Number of all permutations for 4 number subsets is [C(n,4)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) and is O(n^4). Number of all permutations for 2 numbers is C(n,2) and is O(n^2). O(n^2) seems to be OK for the task.

1. Input is: an array `A` with `n` elements, `X`.
2. Generate all permutations for 2 number subsets (that's O(n^2)) and put their sums into array `B` with n^2 elements (also remembering the subsets). Let's denote as `S[B[i]]` the subset (consisting of the two numbers) whose sum is `B[i]`.
3. Sort the `B`, O(n^2*log(n^2)).
4. Walk through the array `B` (O(n^2)) `i = [0,n^2)` and quick search `O(log(n^2)) = O(log(n))` in it for the value `(X - B[i])`. There might be several of them (but not more than n^2).

   4.1. Walk through all the elements with value of `(X - B[i])`, using index `k`.

   4.2. Skip the elements `B[k]` where `S[B[k]]` intersects with `S[B[i]]`. Intersection of two sets with two numbers can be calculated in O(1).

   4.3 If `k` is the index a element where `B[i] + B[k] == X` and `S[B[k]]` doesn't intersect with `S[B[i]]`, then the sum of the sets `S[B[k]]` and `S[B[i]]` are the four sought numbers.

Performance is:
O( n^2 + n^2*log(n^2) + n^2*log(n^2) ) = O( n^2 * log(n^2) ) = O( n^2 * log(n) )

On step four, when we iterate over the multiple matching elements of `B` using nested loop. Yet, total number of iterations of the two nested loops is limited by the `|B|` which is O(n^2). The quick search is not the usual variation but the one which finds the matching element with the lowest index. (Alternatively one can use the usual `bsearch` and since we might have landed in the middle, use two adjacent loops, checking elements in both directions.)

Comment: `log(n^2)` is `2log(n)`, so you're not exceeding the time complexity. This will, however, not account for duplicate elements. Additional checks will be needed for that but it's possible. For example given the array `[1, 2, 3]` and the sums `[ 1+2, 1+3, 2+3 ]`, a desired sum of `9` can be found with `4 + 5`, but we are counting 3 twice then.

Comment: @Anurag: OMG. I had to repeat the math.

Comment: Can you detail the 4th step? How exactly do you deal with duplicates and over/undercounting?

Comment: How do you check if they have an intersection or not? (for example, how do you check S[B[k]] doesn't intersect with S[B[i]]?)

Answer (score 4):

Like a few other posters, it can be done with a hash in O(n^2)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <math.h>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

struct Entry
{
   int a;
   int b;
};

int main () {

   typedef vector<int> VI;

   VI l(5);
   l[0] = 1;
   l[1] = 2;
   l[2] = -1;
   l[3] = -2;
   l[4] = 5;
   l[5] = 6;

   sort(l.begin(), l.end());

   int sumTo = 0;

   typedef multimap<int, Entry> Table;

   typedef pair<int,Entry> PairEntry;

   Table myTbl;

   // N
   for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); ++i)
   {
      // N
      for (int j = i+1; j < l.size(); ++j)
      {
         // Const
         int val = l[i] + l[j];

         // A is always less than B
         Entry ent = {i, j};

         myTbl.insert(PairEntry(val,ent));
      }
   }

   pair<Table::iterator, Table::iterator> range;

   // Start at beginning of array
   for (Table::iterator ita = myTbl.begin();
        ita != myTbl.end();
        ++ita)
   {
      int lookFor = sumTo - ita->first;
      // Find the complement
      range = myTbl.equal_range(lookFor);

      // Const bound
      for (Table::iterator itb = range.first;
           itb != range.second;
           ++itb)
      {
         if (ita->second.a == itb->second.a || ita->second.b == itb->second.b)
         {
            // No match
         }
         else
         {
            // Match
            cout << l[ita->second.a] << " " << l[itb->second.a] << " "
                 << l[ita->second.b] << " " << l[itb->second.b] << endl;

            return 0;
         }
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This meets the requirements, so +1, but it's not O(n^2) as you say. A C++ multimap doesn't give you constant time insertions and lookups, those are logarithmic.

Comment: @IVlad But I suppose changing it to an `unordered_multimap` would have solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

A working Java solution of the algo. provided by Nikita Rybak above..

```
// find four numbers in an array such that they equals to X
 class Pair{
     int i;
     int j;

     Pair(int x,int y){
         i=x;
         j=y;
     }
 }

 public class FindNumbersEqualsSum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         int num[]={1,2,3,4,12,43,32,53,8,-10,4};

         get4Numbers(num, 17);

         get4Numbers(num, 55);
    }

 public static void get4Numbers(int a[],int sum){

    int len=a.length;

    Map<Integer, Pair> sums = new HashMap<Integer, Pair>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        // 'sums' hastable holds all possible sums a[k] + a[l]
        // where k and l are both less than i

        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; ++j) {
            int current = a[i] + a[j];
            int rest = sum - current;
            // Now we need to find if there're different numbers k and l
            // such that a[k] + a[l] == rest and k < i and l < i
            // but we have 'sums' hashtable prepared for that
            if (sums.containsKey(rest)) {
                // found it
                Pair p = sums.get(rest);
                System.out.println(a[i]+" + "+a[j]+" + "+a[p.i] +" + "+a[p.j]+" = "+sum);

            }
        }

        // now let's put in 'sums' hashtable all possible sums
        // a[i] + a[k] where k < i
        for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k) {
            sums.put(a[i] + a[k],new Pair(i, k));
        }
    }
 }
}

 Result:

  4 + 8 + 3 + 2 = 17
  8 + 4 + 4 + 1 = 17
  43 + 8 + 3 + 1 = 55
  32 + 8 + 12 + 3 = 55
  8 + -10 + 53 + 4 = 55
  -10 + 4 + 8 + 53 = 55
```

Comment: This doesnt really handle duplicates -

Comment: Shows 53 + 8 + 4 + 3 = 68   and 
8 + 4 + 53 + 3 = 68

Comment: could you please explain what is "class pair" and why do you use it here?

Answer (score 1):

1) Create an array of all possible pair sums [O(N^2)]

2) Sort this array in ascending order [O(N^2 * Log N)]

3) Now this problem reduces to finding 2 numbers in a sorted array that sum to a given number X, in linear time. Use 2 pointers: a LOW pointer starting from the lowest value, and a HIGH pointer starting from the highest value. If the sum is too low, advance LOW. If the sum is too high, advance HIGH (backwards). Eventually they will find that pair or cross each other (this can be easily proven). This process takes linear time in the size of the array, i.e. O(N ^ 2)

This gives a total time of O(N^2 * log N) as required.

**NOTE** : This method can be generalized for solving the case of M numbers in O(M * N^(M/2) *  log N) time.

-- EDIT --

Actually my response is very similar to Dummy00001's response, except the final lookup, where I use a faster method (though the overall complexity is the same...)

Comment: +1 nice solution. But one problem here: suppose u r searching for `sum=18`. And `a = {2,3,4,5,7,9,10}` now `a[0]+a[1]=5` and `a[2]+a[5]=13`, so `a[0]+a[1]+a[2]+a[5]=18`. But `a[1]+a[2]=7` and `a[0]+a[5]=11` hence `a[0]+a[1]+a[2]+a[5]=18`. so your solution will print these two instead of 1. So how will you tackle the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @Trying: The algorithm isn't required to print a specific set of four; any four distinct numbers having the required sum are ok. The problem with my solution is uniqueness. It may include an array number twice. This can be solved by storing the pairs inside the map as well, and then accepting a match between two pairs only if they have no value in common.

Comment: True. Thanks for your conformation. I was debugging your solution today and found this, hence wanted to conform from the author. Thanks.

Comment: How do you find that "two pairs have no value in common"?

Comment: @Hengameh: For each sum in the sums array, you can also store the indices of the 2 values in the original array. In step 3, to avoid finding false combinations, verify that the 2 indices of LOW have no common value with the 2 indices of HIGH. 
In case that you have K repeated values for LOW and L repeated values for HIGH, and all combinations yield the right sum X, simply check all combinations. The overhead of running this cross check once or more is at most O(N^2), so it doesn't change the overall complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework to me.  But here's what I'd do.

First sort the numbers (there's your n*log(n)).

Now, create pointers to the list, initialize it with the first 4 numbers.  Once you have that, you check the sum of your 4 current numbers with the total.  It should be less than or equal to your search sum (if it's not, you can quit early).  Now all you need to do is traverse rest of your list alternately replacing your pointers with the current value in the list.  This only need to happen once (or really at worst 4 times) so there's your other n, which makes n^2*log(n)

You'll need to keep track of some logic to know if you're over/under your sum and what to do next, but I leave that as your homework assignment.

Comment: _traverse rest of your list alternately replacing your pointers with the current value in the list_ This part sounds extremely vague to me.

Comment: Can you give details how you traverse the list with four pointers ? Do you let the first pointer first go to the end, then the second one etc. ?

Comment: By the way, this would be O(n) + O(n * log(n)) = O(n * log(n)), not O(n) * O(n * log(n))

Comment: so, you mean it can be done in O(nlogn)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to answer your question completely, since I think it is homework and also think that this is easily done.  But I do think that I know why you are having difficulty with an answer, so I will help you out a little bit.

Firstly, you should look into recursion.  That means calling a function from within itself.

Second, you should use a helper function, which is called by the function you want to write.  This function should take as arguments:
- an array of numbers
- the length of the array
- the value you want find members that sum up to
- the number of members of the array that you want to sum up

This function will be called by your other function and passed a 4 for the last argument.  It will then call itself adjusting the arguments as it tries to find results by partial trial and error.

## edit 2

Upon further thought I realized that this not O(n^2), as I claimed earlier (I mentally glossed over the the middle steps).  It is limited by n^4, but may have a lower limit than that due to ample opportunity to short cut in many cases.  I do not believe that this short cutting improves it to the point of n^2, though.

Comment: And how do you prove the complexity of this is as required?

Comment: So you think it's easily done and then end up realising you don't know how to do it. Nice. -1.

Comment: @IVLad: I could have deleted the answer and avoided a down vote, but instead I left it up with a note pointing out the flaws with it.

Comment: Thanks all, after a couple of hours today i have reached similar answers like you.
I don't need all possible 4 numbers, i need only one option.
My solution has also O(n^2) place complexity.

Answer (score 0):

find four elements in array whose sum equal to a given number X
for me following algorithm works:

```
Dim Amt(1 To 10) As Long
Dim i

For i = 1 To 10
    Amt(i) = Val(List1.List(i))
Next i

Dim Tot As Integer
Dim lenth As Integer
lenth = List1.ListCount

'sum of 4 numbers
For i = 1 To lenth
    For j = 1 To lenth
        For k = 1 To lenth
            For l = 1 To lenth
                If i <> j And i <> k And i <> l And j <> k And j <> l And k <> l Then
                    Debug.Print CBAmt(i) & " , " & CBAmt(j) & " , " & CBAmt(k) & " , " & CBAmt(l)
                    If CBAmt(i) + CBAmt(j) + CBAmt(k) + CBAmt(l) = Val(Text1) Then
                        MsgBox "Found"
                        found = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            If found = True Then Exit For
        Next
        If found = True Then Exit For
    Next
    If found = True Then Exit For
Next
```

Comment: This is an O(n^4) solution!

Answer (score 0):

I have written an O(N^^2) running time function which does not use hashtables but handles negative numbers and duplicate numbers apparently OK. I  handle negative numbers in an integer array by adding an large postive number(e.g. 100) to all the integers in the array. Then, I adjust the target by `target += (4 * 100)`. Then when I find a result, I subtract out the 100 from the integers in the result. Here is my code and test cases: Please let me know if this o(N^^2) time complexity.

```
struct maryclaranicholascameron{
    int sum;
    int component1;
    int component2;
};


void Another2PrintSum(int arr[], int arraysize, int target){
    int i(arraysize -1);
    int j(arraysize -2);
    int temp(target);
    int temp2(0);
    int m(0);
    int n(0);
    int sum(0);
    int original_target(target);

    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < arraysize; ctr++){

        sum += arr[ctr];
    }

         for (int ctrn = 0; ctrn < arraysize; ctrn++){
        arr[ctrn] += 100;
    }


    maryclaranicholascameron* temparray = new maryclaranicholascameron[sum + (arraysize *100)];
    memset(temparray, 0, sizeof(maryclaranicholascameron) * (sum + 400));



    for (m = 0; m < arraysize; m++){
        for (n = m + 1; n < arraysize; n++){
                temparray[arr[m] + arr[n]].sum = arr[m]+ arr[n];
                temparray[arr[m] + arr[n]].component1 = m;
                temparray[arr[m] + arr[n]].component2 = n;
        }
    }

    target += (4 * 100);
    original_target = target;

    bool found(false);
    while (i >= 0 && i < arraysize && found == false){
        target -= (arr[i]);
        while(j >= 0 && j < arraysize && found == false){
            temp2 = target;
            target -= (arr[j]);
            if (i != j && temparray[target].sum == target && 
                temparray[target].sum != 0 &&
                temparray[target].component1 != i &&
                temparray[target].component2 != i &&
                temparray[target].component1 != j &&
                temparray[target].component2 != j){
                printf("found the 4 integers i = %d j = %d m = %d n = %d component1 = %d component = %d i %d j %d\n",
                    arr[i] - 100,
                    arr[j] - 100,
                    arr[temparray[target].component1] - 100,
                    arr[temparray[target].component2] - 100,
                    temparray[target].component1,
                    temparray[target].component2,
                    i,
                    j);
                    found = true;
                    break;
            }
            j -= 1;
            target = temp2;
        }
        i -= 1;
        j = i;
        target = original_target;
    }
    if (found == false){
        printf("cannot found the 4 integers\n");
    }
    delete [] temparray;
}

// test cases

int maryclaranicholas[] = {-14,-14,-14,-14,-12 ,-12, -12 ,-12 ,-11, -9,-8,-7,40};
 Another2PrintSum(maryclaranicholas, 13,-2};

int testarray[] = {1,3,4,5,7,10};
Another2PrintSum(testarray, 6, 20);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not criticising this post, yet i see there are lots of improvements that can be made. First, try to name your variables in a more meaningful way so that it would be much more *readable*. Second, your `temparray` only stores **1** pair of indices that would add up to a specific target. What if when you're iterating but found out this one pair would somehow intersect with another in your final loop, but there is another pair that won't? That's essentially why "Sibshops"'s answer uses a *multi-map*.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be reduced to finding all combinations of length 4. For each combination thus obtained, sum the elements and check if it is equal to X.

Comment: what is the time complexity of this solution? could you please provide the code?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be taken as a variation of pascals identity,

here is the complete code :

please excuse as the code is in java :

```
public class Combination {
static int count=0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[] =  {10, 20, 30, 40, 1, 2,4,11,60,15,5,6};
    int setValue = 4;
    getCombination(a, setValue);

}

private static void getCombination(int[] a, int setValue) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int size = a.length;
    int data[] = new int[setValue];
    createCombination(a, data, setValue, 0, 0, size);
    System.out.println(" total combinations : "+count);
}

private static void createCombination(int[] a, int[] data, int setValue,
        int i, int index, int size) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (index == setValue) {

        if(data[0]+data[1]+data[3]+data[2]==91)
        {   count ++;
        for (int j = 0; j < setValue; j++)
            System.out.print(data[j] + " ");
        System.out.println();
        }return;
    }
    // System.out.println(". "+i);
    if (i >= size)
        return;
    // to take care of repetation
    if (i < size - 2) {
        while (a[i] == a[i + 1])
            i++;
    }
    data[index] = a[i];
    // System.out.println(data[index]+" "+index+"  .....");
    createCombination(a, data, setValue, i + 1, index + 1, size);

    createCombination(a, data, setValue, i + 1, index, size);

}
```

}

**Sample input** :

```
int a[] =  {10, 20, 30, 40, 1, 2,4,11,60,15,5,6};
```

**Output :**  :

```
10 20 1 60 
10 30 40 11 
10 60 15 6 
20 30 40 1 
20 60 5 6 
30 40 15 6 
11 60 15 5 
 total combinations : 7
```

Comment: what is the time complexity of this approach?