# Sum of 4 numbers in an array equal to a specific number

Tags: c++, algorithm, subset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [find four elements in array whose sum equal to a given number X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569504/find-four-elements-in-array-whose-sum-equal-to-a-given-number-x)

Given an array of integers both positive and negative integers,find four distinct numbers that sum upto the specific number say 0. `O(n^4)` is obviously not a good solution.
E.g.

An array contains

0,1,-4,3,7,-8, -11

Here,possible solutions are 0,1,-4,3 or 0,1,7,-8 or 1,3,7,-11

Same values can be repeated.It doesn't matter at all.The only thing to keep in mind that 
four numbers chosen should have different indices.That's all.

I found some materials regarding efficient solutions but not much of satisfaction to me.If anyone can help me,you are very welcomed.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, add `homework` tag.

Comment: is trying 3 and check whether the other one exists also O(n^3)?

Comment: This might be helpful. Same question, done in O(n^2). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569504/find-four-elements-in-array-whose-sum-equal-to-a-given-number-x

Comment: @TheZ nope, its not a homework.I was solving sum of two numbers equal to a specific number in O(n).Then,I thought of doing the same thing with 3 or 4 numbers.For 3 numbers,I found solution of O(n^2) ,also O(nlogn),which is satisfactory.Butfor 4 numbers,I couldnt.So asking if you can help.Thanks.

Comment: @Vlad I guess,if N is even averagly large like 10^5 or 10^6.O(n^3) wont be that helpful.But still,it would be great if I can learn it.Atleast better than O(n^4) :P

Comment: @vj: O(n^3) is actually simple: you choose 3 numbers, and the 4th is desired sum - 1st - 2nd - 3rd, so you just need to check if it's in the set (O(1) with hashset).

Comment: @Vlad what if the specific number is the fourth number.That is,sum of three numbers equal to the fourth number within the array ?

Comment: @vj: well, this is exactly the case you are looking for, right?

Comment: yeah.thats y what the above link suggested dint work out for me !!

Answer (score 2):

Well, starting at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM, which is about finding 3 numbers that add up to 0, I would assume that (similar to the related(?) knapsack problem) there's no really great way of doing 4 numbers either.

Now, I'm assuming that the 3SUM algorithm could be adapted to solve the problem of finding 3 numbers that add up to c instead of 0 -- the algorithm given compares with ==0 and <0, so maybe that can be changed to another constant. If that doesn't work you can always multiply every integer with 3 and subtract the constant from each before doing the 3SUM (effectively I want to subtract c/3 from each integer since we're adding 3 of them, but the algorithm says integer numbers...).

The 4th number might introduce another factor "n": iterate over all numbers and incorporate the 4th number into the constant. So that would leave us at n^2 for 3SUM and n^3 for the 4SUM.