# Lower bounding and removing hashing for finding subset of size 4 that adds to a target sum

Tags: algorithm, subset-sum

Finding a subset of four elements that add to a target sum S can be done in O(n^2) time, by hashing all pairwise sums x and also hashing S - x until a non-trivial collision is found. However hashing has issues; is it possible to remedy this to achieve guaranteed O(n^2) time to find a 4-element subset that adds to a target sum S without hashing, and more importantly, is it known whether it's possible to do better than O(n^2) time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [find four elements in array whose sum equal to a given number X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569504/find-four-elements-in-array-whose-sum-equal-to-a-given-number-x)

Comment: [3SUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3sum) is an easier problem and can't be solved in less than O(n²) time (as far as we know), so presumably this can't be either.

Comment: @Dukeling I see this is a partial duplicate because O(n^2) time has been found but the worst-case complexity is a different question. Maybe it's possible to prove that 4SUM is Omega(n^2) or something close even if it can't be proved for 3SUM

Comment: If the target numbers are integers in a range of size C (for example, A <= x_i <= A + C), then it is possible to compute the pairwise sums in O(C log C) using FFT

Comment: If the linked post answers the rest of your question, I suggest you edit your question to focus on the remaining part (but you may have more luck on [cs.se] with that). Although, isn't is sufficient that no-one's been able to come up with a faster than O(n²) algorithm for a presumably simpler problem? Do you really need an explicit proof?

Comment: The interesting question here is whether we can shave the log (n^2 log n -> n^2) without something with a bad worst case (e.g., hashing). Unfortunately, we don't know how to sort S + S in time O(n^2).