# find four integers that sum to a given value

Tags: algorithm, hash

Given a group of *n* integers - *S* that belongs to ℤ.
All the integers in *S* are in the range of 0 to ⌈*nlgn*⌉.
I need to find whether there are 4 integers in *S* whose sum equals to a given number *X*.

I know there is a solution of *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* using hashing, and there are some other solutions of *O(n<sup>2</sup>lgn)*.

Is there any chance that this specific question can be solved in n<sup>2</sup> time without using hashing?

If using hashing, is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* the worst case, or its anticipation?

Comment: can you include a worked example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Regarding the last question: O(sth) is defined as worst case.  So if whoever said that with hashing you have O(n²) was regarding to some anticipated value (average or whatever), then this someone didn't use O() properly.

Comment: @GMc basically some students say it is possible to solve in *O(n^2)*  time without a hash table.
but as I said, I couldn't find any solution like this at the web, therefore, I ask here if there is any way to solve it without hashing in *O(n^2)*
Alfe please see   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569504/find-four-elements-in-array-whose-sum-equal-to-a-given-number-x

Comment: look [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2973/generalised-3sum-k-sum-problem), might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @Yonlif thanks I have been reading there, but can't find a definite answer for my question...

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
sums = array of vectors of size (n log n) * 2

for index1, num1 in numbers:
    for index2, num2 in numbers:
        sums[num1 + num2].append((index1, index2))

idx1 = 0
idx2 = x
while idx1 < idx2:
    if any pair in sums[idx1] doesnt share an index with any pair of sums[idx2]:
        any of those combinations generates the sum x
    idx1 += 1
    idx2 -= 1
```

As the numbers are in a small range, we don´t need hashing, we can use simple arrays with the sum as the index. To generate sums, we spend O(n^2) time. To then check if there is a sum, it is also O(n^2) because we never look at the candidates in sums[idx] more than once each and there are n^2 of those candidates. This part can probably be improved but won´t help for the overall complexity.

Comment: Having a unique sum point to an arbitrarily sized vector could be considered conceptually as a hash.

Comment: True, hard to know if something else is expected

Comment: @juvian thanks!
being curious, is there any way to solve it on-place without creating an additional array/hash table in O(n^2)? for example, sort the numbers then use 4 pointers to move through the index's

Comment: how will you handle duplicates?

Comment: @omrib40 for that you would need to generate the sums in order and can't think of a way to do that. What do you mean by duplicates?

Comment: @juvian you might have different numbers that their sum is equal, then how would you place them if they must be in the same index?

Comment: @omrib40 thats why we put all pairs of indexes that sum the same in the same vector. The sum is just an index to this vector of pair of indexes